# An exception occurred processing JSP page /customerLogin.jsp at line

Tags: java, string, jsp

Im trying to print login error message in login screen.

```
<%   
   errorMessage = request.getParameter("errorMessage"); 
    if(errorMessage.equals(null))
     errorMessage = "Error: " +request.getParameter("errorMessage");
       else
        errorMessage="";
  out.println(errorMessage);

   %>
```

Intitally this request.getParameter will not return any value. hence it will return null. But once user enters username password and submits it will return error message.

Im getting the following error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /customerLogin.jsp at line 18

15:   errorMessage = request.getParameter("errorMessage"); 
16:     
17:         
18:   out.println(errorMessage.toString().equals(null));
19:             
20:  %>
21:
```

Comment: Dont use equals method for checking null... Use errorMessage == null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like what your stackstrace pointing out.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /customerLogin.jsp at line 18

 out.println(errorMessage.toString().equals(null));
```

You should not use equals method for checking null object. Always remember
`==` checks for object reference equality while `.equals()` tests for value equality.

So instead.

```
if(errorMessage.equals(null))
```

Use

```
if(errorMessage == null)
```

or use .equals() if when you expect empty string rather than null.

```
if(errorMessage.toString().equals(""))
```